# Close the current tab and go to parent Tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a link on a webpage that would close current active tab in a browser without closing other tabs in the browser. When user clicks close link, an alert message should appear asking user to confirm with two buttons, "YES" and "NO". If user clicks "YES", close that page and go to the parent tab and if press s no do nothing.?

It's kind of bad flow but i am searching for a solution.

Comment: Looking for the same! Just I have/had opened new window instead of tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:
this may close the current tab for you.

```js
if (confirm("Close Window?")) {
    window.top.location.reload(true);
    window.top.close();
}else{
    // write down code the code that you want ot execute on clicking on " No ".
}
```

Comment: Is there any way that , when we close current widow(newly opened), should refresh the widow from where we came.

Comment: @SujVan save referral url and redirect back after closing. refresh get resolved

Comment: you can do it before just by adding as edited code and give up voting if answer would help full to you.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar: Can you explain litte bit?

Comment: window.top.location.reload(true); // will refresh the top.location( parent's tab ) with cache = "true" if you don't want to allow cache then you can put false as a argument.

Comment: just like  return url, save url through get like ?return=http://etc.com
after closing then redirect back with parem url.

Answer (score 0):

close the current tab and go to parent tab with reload

```
 window.opener.location.reload();
 window.top.close();
```